# Was anyone ever killed/maimed in G.I. Joe: A Real American Hero?

Tags: gi-joe-real-american-hero

Like many American boys who grew up in the 1980s, I loved the [G.I. Joe: A Real American Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.I._Joe:_A_Real_American_Hero_(1985_TV_series)).

Looking back, I think just about every episode of the show included at least some scenes of intense combat -- but I'm also pretty sure that in all those battles, no soldiers on either side were ever killed or even maimed. People would shoot at each other with those laser guns, but no one ever got hit. And when planes or helicopters would get shot down, the pilots always parachute out.

Am I forgetting something, or **is it true that no one ever died in battle in the G.I. Joe: A Real American Hero**?

(Note that I am referring only to the TV show, and not including GI Joe The Movie, in which Serpentor takes over Cobra)

Answer (score 9):

In the episode "Worlds without end", the Joes travel to a parallel universe where G.I.Joe was eradicated and Cobra won. They even run into the skeletons of a few dead Joes. But no one was killed on screen.

Comment: This is the first thing that came to mind when I read the question. Amazing that I can even remember the episode after all this time.

Answer (score 6):

I asked a friend and his response was:

*There was an episode that had a handful of the JOE team searching for the others. Steeler was really on the edge of insanity because nothing made sense. They found the old JOE base, and ran the records to find everyone else had been killed. I can't remember if it was one of those "skewed universes" or a secret COBRA land, where they made it like they were victorious*.

Is this the episode that SystemDown refers to?

Comment: Yeah, thats the one. Pretty good episode.